# Uncaught TypeError: 30.239670000000004: type 'minified:E8' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I publish my website with flutter web. It work fine on localhost but when i open web link it shown [Uncaught TypeError: 30.239670000000004: type 'minified:E8' is not a subtype of type 'String']

Comment: Started facing the same issue. Website runs okay locally but now it fails when run in release mode with: **TypeError: Instance of 'minified:cb': type 'minified:cb' is not a subtype of type 'minified:dg'** . Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I am running with `Flutter Channel Stable 3.0.0`, `Dart version 2.17.0`

Comment: I also start getting error in flutter web "Uncaught Error: TypeError: null: type 'minified:uU' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Answer (score 0):

One of my packages is causing this problem while running in the canvasKit. Rather than removing that package, I built the web release using the HTML rendering command:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
```

It works on mobile phones and desktops in chrome and safari. Desktop Firefox is still causing the problem.